# navbar changing background color with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a portfolio website that I have 9 projects. I am using jQuery cycle plugin to cycle through the projects. I need each section to have a different navbar background color and header colors.

My html:

```
<header>
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="left">
        <li class="list-item"><button id="prev"></button></li>
        <li class="list-item dark-item" id="play"><a class="fancybox-media" href="https://vimeo.com/60763684">play</a></li>
        <li class="list-item dark-item"><button id="more">view more</button></li>
        <li class="list-item"><button id="next"></button></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="list-item">
          <a href="#">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
          <a href="#">blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
          <a href="#">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header> 

  <div id="wrap">
    <section id="one">
      <div class="top-bg">
        <iframe class="hidden" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/56999419?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=ef5e6f"frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="top-header">
          <h1>Sonhos, Rêves, Dreams</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mi magna, ultrices nec lacus vitae, tempor condimentum velit. Sed facilisis pellentesque diam et porttitor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="hidden-content hidden">
            <h1>Hidden-Content</h1>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="two">
      <div class="top-bg">
        <iframe class="hidden" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/60763684?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=ef5e6f"frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="top-header">
          <h1>The Me Bird</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mi magna, ultrices nec lacus vitae, tempor condimentum velit. Sed facilisis pellentesque diam et porttitor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-content hidden">
        <h1>Hidden-Content</h1>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="three">
      <div class="top-bg">
        <iframe class="hidden" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/60603563?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=ef5e6f"frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="top-header">
          <h1>Le Petit Pirate</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mi magna, ultrices nec lacus vitae, tempor condimentum velit. Sed facilisis pellentesque diam et porttitor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden-content hidden">
        <h1>Hidden-Content</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
```

and my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wrap').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 0, 
    next:   '#next', 
    prev:   '#prev' 
    });

    $('#more').on('click', function(){
        $('.hidden-content').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.hidden-content').addClass('show');
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        $(window).scrollTop(y+100);
    });

    $('#prev, #next').on('click', function () {
        $('.hidden-content').removeClass('show');
        $('.hidden-content').addClass('hidden');
    });

    $('#two').ready(function() {
        $('nav').css('background', '#b1e0eb');
    });

    $('#play').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('iframe').removeClass('hidden');
        $('iframe').addClass('show');
        $('iframe').attr('autoplay', '1');
        $('.top-header, .info').css('z-index', '-1');
    });
});
```

If I do this, all the sections get the color I'm adding with jquery. But I would like each of my projects to have different colors.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Give each section a unique ID and have the Jquery assign the unique background to the respective ID.

Comment: Hi @dwreck08, they have unique IDs already. If you look at the code, the first section has an ID of "one", the second section's ID is "two" and so on. But I have only one navbar. I want the navbar to change colors dinamically, when the sections opacity is 1. Because that's when the content for the section shows-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

in your css

```
.bgcolor1 { background: blue; }
.bgcolor2 { background: green; }
.bgcolor3 { background: yellow; }
etc
```

in your jquery

```
var bgcolornumber = 1;

$('#more').on('click', function(){
    $('.hidden-content').removeClass('hidden');
    $('nav').removeClass('bgcolor'+bgcolornumber-1); // this probably not needed, but use it to remove the previous background class
    $('.hidden-content').addClass('show');
    $('nav').addClass('bgcolor'+bgcolornumber);  // adds the new class with the new background color
    bgcolornumber += 1; // adds 1 to the var, so you can grab the next background color from css
```

Comment: Hi @LowerClassOverflowian, I don't want to change the .hidden-content. For that is no problem. It's the header navbar background-color that I want to change for each of the 9 projects. And I have only one navbar that stays on the bottom of the page, while I cycle through the projects clicking the ">" and "<" buttons. I want to change the navback color when each project shows up.

Comment: @jppag I see. Well, it should work the same way, with nav, see edit. Without seeing a fiddle or anything, it's hard to tell exactly where to place my suggested jquery code, but something like what I posted should work for you by adding it somewhere in your code.

Comment: It's funny. It works only when I click two times ( starts changing colors on the third project). And When it reaches the last ".bgcolor" it doesn't change anymore. But the thing is, I would like to set specific navbar background colors to specific sections. For instance: #one and #three would be red, and #two and #four would be yellow, and #five and #six would be green... @LoweClassOverflowian